# Use of loop with if function in a VBA Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working my way though the various ways to use IF function and now I'm  a little stuck with loops.

I know how to just loop if I have to put it in to cells, but I don't know how to loop it when there is a IF and when I have to take the value from a combobox.

This is the code without loop

```
cR = ComboBox2.Value
If IsNull(cR) = False Then
tsheet.Range("B1").Value = cR
End If
cR = ""
cR = ComboBox3.Value
If IsNull(cR) = False Then
tsheet.Range("B2").Value = cR
End If
cR = ""
cR = ComboBox4.Value
If IsNull(cR) = False Then
tsheet.Range("B3").Value = cR
End If
```

So I can imagine the loop would look something like:

```
For i = 2 To 4
For k = 1 To 3
If Not ComboBox(i).Value = vbNullString
Range("B", k).Value = ComboBox(i).Value
next
End Sub
```

Comment: `If` isn't a function. Also, the `cR = ""` in the original code is pointless. You don't have to reset a variable before reusing it.

Comment: I was not sure about that cR that's why I put it there. I was trying to find something about it if I had to reset it but didn't find anything.. thanks for the input. if "IF" is not a function what do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it thus (assuming the code is in a userform).

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 4
    If Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
        Range("B" & i - 1).Value = Me.Controls("ComboBox" & i).Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: that was a clever way to take care of the cell number. didn't think of that. Thanks for the help SJR

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have many comboboxes you could link the comboboxes to a range of cells and then use Excel formulas; e.g.
B2.formula    =IF(Combo2Val)<>"",Combo2Val,"")
No need for VBA.